# Is it possible to detect PHP cURL configuration?

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I'm using a PHP cURL script to connect to an API that uses rate limiting by passing the connection through a proxy. I tested file_get_contents and cURL and cURL seems to have much more flexibility, the problem is I'm using GoDaddy hosting and for whatever reason this script runs correctly on other hosts but with GoDaddy it doesn't function correctly. It's almost as if GoDaddy has their PHP cURL module configured to not accept proxy connections. I'm trying to determine if there is any additional lines of code I need to make this function on their hosting or if it's just not possible to do. Note: I've tried file_get_contents with a stream context proxy config with no results on GoDaddy also, is there a way to detect config or determine if this is just not possible to do?

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url="https://ipleak.net/json/";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '45.63.52.250:3128');    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
$error = curl_error($ch);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);
print_r($error);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); `

Comment: You need to swap these two lines around if you want to see where its going wrong. $error = curl_error($ch);
$response = curl_exec($ch);. You have to do the exec before you can check for errors